# How to save a list of URIs matching a pattern in Marklogic with corb?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I need some help with MarkLogic, XQuery & corb,

I have millions of documents in the database, I'm trying to write the XQuery to saved the matched uris.

urisVersions.xqy

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $uris := cts:uri-match("*versions/*version-*")

return (fn:count($uris), $uris)
```

urisSave.xqy

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;

let $uri := $URI 
return xdmp:save("/tmp/test",$uri)
```

save-job.properties

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI= xcc://user:admin@localhost:8000/
URIS-MODULE=urisVersions.xqy|ADHOC
XQUERY-MODULE=urisSave.xqy|ADHOC
THREAD-COUNT=10
```

Getting below error
SEVERE: fatal error
com.marklogic.developer.corb.CorbException: Invalid argument type at URI: /12312/versions/item/papkov.xml.version-24

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: That error is because the second parameter of `xdmp:save()` needs to be a node. You are providing a string with the URI. You could save a `text()` node: `xdmp:save("/tmp/test", text{$uri})` however, each invocation of the process module would be fighting to overwrite that "/tmp/test" file - not good. You want to use the CoRB task that writes output of the process module to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the job with the [`PROCESS-TASK`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-TASK) option to use the `com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask` class, which will write the results of each process module invocation to an output file. You can configure where to write the file and the filename with [`EXPORT-FILE-NAME`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#EXPORT-FILE-NAME) and [`EXPORT-FILE-DIR`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#EXPORT-FILE-DIR) options. If you don't configure the EXPORT-FILE-DIR and just give it a filename with EXPORT-FILE-NAME it writes relative from where CoRB is launched.

```
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=versionsURIs.txt
```

Change your process module to simply return the $URI value:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
$URI
```

If you just want to write the URIs to a file and aren't transforming or doing any processing, then you could use the [ModuleExecutor](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/ModuleExecutor-Tool) class and have it write the results of the cts:uri-match directly to the output file.

Comment: Thanks, @Mads Hansen